# cant pass post-data with jquery on return-key

Tags: jquery

This is my code, I want to send the value of the textfield with the classid "#note" to the php site at dash/add after return is hit. but it doesn't work.

```
$(function() {
$('#note').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var note = $('#note').val();
            $.post("index.php/dash/add", {note:note}, function() {
            $('.sort').load("index.php/dash/add");
         });
    }
}); });
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, try making your textfield have `id="note"`, then using `$('#note')` in your jQuery.

Comment: I just did it but it didn't change anything (yet).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if it makes a difference.  If you have more than one element with class="note", then it will make a difference; otherwise, probably not.

Comment: Oh okay, so this was the only element. But it's now an id.

Comment: Basically seems to work, see prototype here:  http://jsfiddle.net/GYXN6/  The post returns a 404 (naturally, because there's nobody listening for that URL on jsfiddle), but the post is getting sent with the right value.

Comment: Hmm, it just doesn't work on my machine. I don't get an 404 (the site exists of course), but it doesn't show the sended, stuff. And it php which I'm using in this case, the line is simply: echo $_POST['note'] (actually I'm using it with codeigniter, so it's something like $this->input->post('note'); but I tried both ways, still doesnt work.)

Comment: changed now the adress, get an 404-error code than too. So it means, something is send. what could be the problem now?

Comment: If you're getting a 404, it means that you need a script listening at index.php/dash/add.  I can't help with the codeigniter stuff, b/c I don't know much about it.  But I'd appreciate an upvote if my comments helped so far :)

Comment: Your coments did help of course. Thank you. No, I don't get a 404-error. I said, I changed the name of the files so I could find out if firebug would send me such an error and it did. But the post-data still isn't shown.

Comment: On my machine (I'm using Firefox), the POST data is showing on that JSFiddle link I posted above.  See if you can see the POST data there too.  Do you have a HTML element like this: <textarea id="note"></textarea> ?

Comment: yeah, exactly. I cannot see any post-data there.

Comment: I'm not sure, I can clearly see the post data.  You're not expecting to see the parameter on the end of the URL, like this ...dash/add?note=blah, right?  That would be a GET request.